# WP appending -2 to the end of my slug

Tags: slug

I would like to create a page on wordpress with this URL: https://my-website.org/landing-page/

However, it seems that the slug /landing-page/ has already been created in the past because it does not return a "404 Page not found" error but redirects to the home page: https://my-website.org/

When I try to create a page with the following Url: https://my-website.org/landing-page/ wordpress generates a new page with a -2 at the end of the slug.

( Next Url: https://my-website.org/landing-page-2/)

This is something I absolutely want to avoid.

I've searched all my pages, articles and media to see if an element links to https://my-website.org/landing-page/ but I've found absolutely nothing. I don't have any pages in the trash. I didn't have a category with the same name as my page.

I purged the cache in the LiteSpeed cache plugin and that didn't work.

However, I've just noticed something strange:

I've tried to create a post (and not a page as previously tried) and wordpress generates the url I want: https://my-website.org/landing-page/

However, when I click on "Edit with oxygen" to edit the page, it sends me to the oxygen editing interface on the site's home page: https://my-website.org/

I've modified the page to check which URL the interface modifies and it's the home page it's modifying: https://my-website.org/

Can you help me find a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure it's not in the trash? Or that it's not been set as the slug for the page that's set as the homepage? Note that oxygen builder is offtopic here as are all 3rd party plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a Page. WordPress is very picky about slugs sometimes. You might have to dig in the database's `wp_posts` table and see what other post exists somewhere with that name - sometimes it can be an odd thing like a Media Library (image) file.

Once you find it, if you completely delete it - preferably through wp-admin so all its postmeta gets deleted too - you should then be able to publish a new Page (which is also going to be in the `wp_posts` table) with the slug you want, without WP adding the "-2".

Comment: My home page had the slug I wanted to create but as it was set as the home page the slug was not visible in the wordpress interface. Thank you very much for your help!